# Kotlin coroutines - order of printing logs

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I have a question about the test code below.

```
import kotlinx.coroutines.*

fun main() {
  val kotlin = "Hello kotlin"
  println(kotlin)
  myMethod()
}

fun myMethod() { 
    println("inside my method ${Thread.currentThread().name}")
    GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.Default) {
        for (i in 1..5) {
            if (i == 1) {
                println("At 1 ${Thread.currentThread().name}")
                println("Going to suspend")
                heavyWork()
            } else
                println("Done printing $i")
            }
    }
    println("Done")
}

suspend fun heavyWork() { 
    withContext(Dispatchers.Default) {
        async {
            for (i in 1..5) {
                delay(100)
            }
            println("Done with heavy work")
        }
    }
}
```

The output of the code is always,

```
At 1 DefaultDispatcher-worker-1 @coroutine#1 
Going to suspend 
Hello kotlin
inside my method main
Done
```

My questions:

My understanding is the `launch` method is run only after the main thread has completed running `println(kotlin)` and the first `println` within `myMethod()`.  So I was hoping the order in which the lines printed should always be,

```
Hello kotlin
inside my method main
At 1 DefaultDispatcher-worker-1 @coroutine#1
Going to suspend
Done
```

However, I ran several times and everytime the order of the log is as shown in the first output. The new coroutine is not even launched until the main thread reaches `GlobalScope.launch` so I wonder how the `println` within `GlobalScope.launch` always gets printed first?

Comment: Interesting, I can only reproduce it in Kotlin Playground, but not locally.

Comment: Yep! I just realized after your comment it happens only in the playground. Maybe something I should just ignore and move on. Thank you for looking into this.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following minimal example to reproduce* the behaviour you are witnessing:

```
suspend fun main() {
    print("foo")
    CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
        print("bar")
    }.join()
}
```

We invoke `print` on the main thread and after that we spawn a coroutine which also invokes `print`. The order in which the output appears will not be deterministic. Sometimes it will be

> foobar

and sometimes

> barfoo

Now why is that?

Note that we have two threads running in parallel. The main thread and the coroutine.

The output will not be processed right away when `print` is called because of buffering. `print` will not block until the output is actually shown on stdout.

Instead, the output will be shown the moment a thread flushes its stdout buffer. It not deterministic which thread will flush its buffer first.

---

<sub>* On my local machine it "always" only prints "foo" and on the playground it "always" prints "barfoo". See: https://pl.kotl.in/Y13P_Sm1G</sub>

Comment: No, your example is not the same as the question. The printing of `foo` and `bar` are concurrent. The question's printing of `Hello kotlin` should "happen before"  `At 1 DefaultDispatcher-worker-1 @coroutine#1`.

Comment: @GeorgeLeung You're right, thank you! I corrected that. I still think the basic reasoning is correct.

Comment: @GeorgeLeung Actually taking a step back my initial example was not wrong, I think. We have two threads running in parallel, main and a couroutine on another thread. Just because we invoke print on the main thread first does not mean that it will be processed. print does not block until ouput is shown on stdout.

Spawning two coroutines as I initially did, actually reflects that too. Still, the example I gave now might be more obvious as comparison for a reader.

Answer (score 0):

Your understanding of Kotlin coroutines is correct.

It's a quirk of Kotlin Playground.

Or to be precise, the [code runner](https://github.com/AlexanderPrendota/kotlin-compiler-server) behind it.

---

The server creates a subprocess to run your code.

The wrapper sends `System.out` and `System.err` to a `ByteArrayOutputStream`. After your `main` finishes, it swithces stdout back, and prints the content of the `ByteArrayOutputStream` in JSON form.

https://github.com/AlexanderPrendota/kotlin-compiler-server/blob/3bc8c4b71b98d5ddac95289ce6b1fc25d91a4320/executors/src/main/kotlin/JavaRunnerExecutor.kt

---

The server then parses the subprocess stdout.

https://github.com/AlexanderPrendota/kotlin-compiler-server/blob/3bc8c4b71b98d5ddac95289ce6b1fc25d91a4320/src/main/kotlin/com/compiler/server/model/ProgramOutput.kt#L30

---

As you have coroutines running after `main` returns, their `println` is sent to stdout - after the statement `System.setOut(defaultOutputStream)`, and before the statement `print(mapper.writeValueAsString(outputObj))`.

The server then concatenates the stray output with the well-formed output, putting the stray output first and creating your confusion.

If you check the `Network` in your browser, you can see the output is
`"text":"At 1 DefaultDispatcher-worker-1 @coroutine#1\nGoing to suspend\n<outStream>Hello kotlin\ninside my method main\nDone\n</outStream>"`