# Why does the Kotlin coroutine output "A B" even with a delay?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I have the following Kotlin code snippets using coroutines, and I'm puzzled by the output. Can someone explain why the output is "A B" in both cases?

```kotlin
// Code Snippet 1
fun main() {
  CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch { 
        print("A")
    }
    print("B")
}
```

output: AB

```kotlin
// Code Snippet 2
fun main() {
    CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch { 
        delay(200)
        print("A")
    }
    print("B")
}
```

output AB

i have ran this code on kotlin playground ( link - [kotlin playground](https://pl.kotl.in/AH3V7Rj_I)
I am not able to understand why A prints before B even after adding a delay of 200ms

Comment: have you by any chance, try with a longer delay? You'll also have a surprise there I think, because "A" will most likely never be printed in your current code, as the program will terminate before that. I'd recommend reading the documentation on how coroutines work.

Comment: @AlexT you are actually right about never printing "A". Even delay of 1 second will be enough to see that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Interesting. I would expect at least the second case to only print `B`, because the program terminates before `A` gets the chance to be printed. This is actually what I get when running your code in the IDE.

Your playground link uses `println`, not `print`, and yet prints this weird `A B` output on the same line. This might be a bug in the Kotlin playground's stdout handling when outputting from different threads. Don't trust concurrent output from the playground I suppose.

EDIT: I confirm, the payload received by the playground contains `"text": "A\n<outStream>B\n</outStream>"`, which seems to explain the bad display of concurrent output (only the main thread's output is wrapped in `<outStream>` here).

This bug aside, you should note that you don't wait for the coroutine you launch in any way here. This means that any execution order is technically possible: the main body can print B before or after the launched coroutine executes, and the program can even terminate before the launched coroutine executes or finishes.

You could use `Thread.sleep()` at the end to block the main thread while waiting for the other coroutine to complete, but that's not idiomatic with coroutines.

If you want to automatically wait for the coroutine to complete, you should use structured concurrency (for instance use a `runBlocking` or a `suspend fun main()`+`coroutineScope` here):

```kotlin
fun main(): Unit = runBlocking {
    launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
        delay(200)
        println("A")
    }
    println("B")
}
```

`runBlocking` will automatically wait for child coroutines to finish before returning, so your main thread will be blocked waiting for `A` to be printed, which will prevent the program from terminating too early.

Comment: Somehow just putting `Thread.sleep(1000)` after the `println("B")` in the second example does result in the expected output

Comment: @Ivo because `sleep` blocks the thread I suppose and prevents program from terminating

Comment: "Don't trust concurrent output from the playground I suppose". i guess the learning here is this

Comment: i need any explaination about why this happens or any reason why putting Thread.sleep at the end results in the expected output and i will mark you accepted

Comment: @NeoWakeup If you're talking about the playground bug not being visible in the case of `Thread.sleep`, I really don't know (I don't know how the playground works). When running the code normally (on your machine), is there some behaviour you don't understand?

Comment: @NeoWakeup Maybe this is an internal optimization used by `println()`. Writes have to be synchronized, but at the same time calling `println()` shouldn't cause any delays, so maybe it writes to a per-thread buffer and flushes periodically. And for some reason we observe this behavior in the Playground only. But if we can't reproduce this locally, then we can really only guess.

Comment: @broot what I refer to as a "bug" in the playground is only the display of `A B` on the same line. The fact that `A` is printed before `B` is technically not a bug since no synchronization happens in this code (so it's a valid output to have A first)

Comment: @broot I have detailed the cause in [another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75714151/kotlin-coroutines-order-of-printing-logs/75760394#75760394). I have a [fix](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin-compiler-server/pull/618) proposed, but it's been ignored for a while.